# Enabling Clipboard in LightDM? (16.04)

Tags: 16.04, login, password, lightdm, clipboard

I am not able to use the clipboard on the LightDM login page for Ubuntu 16.04

Usecase:
Login using TeamViewer, and I want to paste my password in from a password manager.

Since it doesn't work I have to type it in every time. Right clicking the password textfield also doesn't give me a contextual menu

[Login Screen Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSuLe.png)

Note: Once I am logged in, the clipboard works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it I discovered is to just use `xdotool` to remotely type in the password via ssh:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt install xdotool -y
echo -n "Password:"
read -s pass
export DISPLAY=:0
xdotool type $pass
xdotool key Return
pass=""
```